# Where does SQLAlchemy filtering for PostgreSQL server happen? (flask-sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, flask-sqlalchemy, gcloud

I am an amateur web developer who's using PostgreSQL servers increasingly in my applications. Since I try to keep my costs to a minimum or even 0, I've been looking into options for PostgreSQL hosting services that may offer a bit more than my free 10.000 rows in Heroku Postgres. I've been looking at Google Cloud SQL and AWS RDS for PostgreSQL. Both seem fine, but I'd like to ask the community which one they think would be better/cheaper. Also, a more general question:
GCloud has a fee on networking: x cents / gb transferred outside of the region. To minimize transferred data size, I've been thinking about optimizing my SQLAlchemy queries, which up to now have looked like this:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
data = User.query.all()
filtered data = filtered_data(data, some_criterium)
```

Would this be, instead a better way to do it? Does cls.query.filter_by() filter the data on the PostgreSQL host or locally?

```
data = User.query.filter_by(username="some_username").first()
```

Thank you for to anyone who is kind enough to offer their opinion.

Answer (score 2):

`session.query` and its methods always return a new `query` object.  In practice, this means that SQLAlchemy constructs and updates a representation of an SQL query in the Python application until the query is iterated over or a method like `.first`, `.one` or `.all` is called: at this point the SQL query is executed in the database server.

Generally, filtering results is going to be faster in the database server than in Python, so you should favour filtering in the database server over filtering in Python code.